# How can I sort a table based two fields using Anko in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, anko

I use  Anko to operate SQLite table, I hope to sort a list based the field `isFavorite` first, then based the `createdDate`

For example, input *Source Data*, and I get the *Sort Result Data*

But the code `return myList.sortedBy{it.isFavorite}.sortedBy{ it.createdDate}` can't get the correct result, how can I fix it?

**Source Data**

[image]

**Sort Result Data  (I hope to get )**

[image]

**Structure**

```
data class MRecord (
    var _id: Long,     
    var isFavorite: Bool,   
    var createdDate: Long
)
```

**Code**

```
var myList=select(tableName).parseList { MDBRecord(HashMap(it)) }        
return myList.sortedBy{it.isFavorite}.sortedBy{ it.createdDate}
```

**Added Content**

To madhead: Thanks!

```
data class MRecord(
    var id: Long,
    var isFavorite: Long,
    var createdDate: Long
)


val list = listOf(
        MRecord(1, 1, 100),
        MRecord(2, 0, 200),
        MRecord(3, 1, 300)
)
```

I hope to get the result

```
1, 1, 100
3, 1, 300
2, 0, 200
```

but the code  `println(list.sortedWith(compareBy({ !it.isFavorite }, MRecord::createdDate)))` will not work because isFavorite is Long, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `myList.sortedBy{it.isFavorite}.sortedBy{ it.createdDate}` will not give you correct results, because it is basically equal to `myList.sortedBy{ it.createdDate}` (only the last sorting applies). What you need is a comparator that takes multiple fields into account and looks like [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) is what you need:

> Creates a comparator using the sequence of functions to calculate a result of comparison. The functions are called sequentially, receive the given values a and b and return Comparable objects. As soon as the Comparable instances returned by a function for a and b values do not compare as equal, the result of that comparison is returned from the Comparator.

So, check this out:

```
data class MRecord(
    var id: Long,
    var isFavorite: Boolean,
    var createdDate: Long
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = listOf(
        MRecord(1, true, 10),
        MRecord(2, false, 20),
        MRecord(3, true, 30)
    )

    println(list)

    println(list.sortedWith(compareBy({ !it.isFavorite }, MRecord::createdDate)))
}
```

Note how you can mix lambdas and function references.

**Edit for `Long` isFavorite**:

```
data class MRecord(
    var id: Long,
    var isFavorite: Long,
    var createdDate: Long
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = listOf(
        MRecord(1, 1, 100),
        MRecord(2, 0, 200),
        MRecord(3, 1, 300)
    )

    println(list.sortedWith(compareByDescending<MRecord> { it.isFavorite }.then(compareBy(MRecord::createdDate))))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code works well, but how can I do if I  hope to get a descending result of createdDate ? BTW `list.sortedWith(compareBy({ !it.isFavorite }, MRecord::createdDate.reverse))` isn't work

Comment: Try `list.sortedWith(compareBy<MRecord>{ !it.isFavorite }.thenDescending(compareBy(MRecord::createdDate)))`

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?